# tensorflow takes a lot time to restore the model using tf.train.saver

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am currently using tensorflow-gpu 1.0.0
It takes me a few seconds to restore a ckpt file（500M） before. 
But today it takes me almost 2 min to restore the model. 
I check the protobuf, it's a cpp version. 
So, any idea why this happen? I did not do anything ,it just come into this situation